# Remove ?preview=true from the address of custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

For some reason because i am using a custom function the preview doesn't work.

```
http://www.domain.com/template-for-rent/?preview=true
```

leads to 404 Page not found.

However,

```
http://www.domain.com/template-for-rent/
```

works even if I don't publish the post.

is there anyway to use htaccess or a custom function to remove `?preview=true` from all URLs of custom post types i am previewing?

My custom function is:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'filterslash_post_type_link', 11, 2);

function filterslash_post_type_link( $post_link, $post ){ $post_link = home_url("/$post->post_name/"); return $post_link; }
```

Comment: Which "custom function" and why might it interfere with previews? That is likely issue worth fixing here.

Comment: Ok, i have added my custom function which i believe is the source of the problem - if you could double check this on your wordpress installation then we will be 100% certain this is the issue

Comment: You seem to be changing _link_ to posts without actually changing how WP _creates and understands_ (rewrites) them. What is your CPT registration code and original links it's producing?

Comment: Rarst i am not sure how to answer your question here..